# What's the purpose of Object(this) in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Studying the polyfill for the find method written on the MDN web docs, there's a particular line that I'm not following, let me share the code

```
if (!Array.prototype.find) {
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'find', {
    value: function(predicate) {
      if (this == null) {
        throw TypeError('"this" is null or not defined');
      }

      var o = Object(this);

      var len = o.length >>> 0;

      if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
        throw TypeError('predicate must be a function');
      }

      var thisArg = arguments[1];

      var k = 0;

      while (k < len) {
        var kValue = o[k];
        if (predicate.call(thisArg, kValue, k, o)) {
          return kValue;
        }
        k++;
      }

      return undefined;
    },
    configurable: true,
    writable: true
  });
}
```

My question is with the expression `var o = Object(this);`. What's the purpose of doing so instead of doing `var o = this`?. Printing the value in both  described cases returns the same object.

Is this an abbreviated way of calling `var o = new Object(this);`?

I have removed the comments from the method to shorten the text, here's the link to the polyfill implementation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill

Thanks!

Comment: Your answer is in the preceding comment: `// 1. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In strict mode, `this` isn't always an object. `Object(this)` makes sure that `o` is an object, not a primitive.

Here's an example of `this` being a primitive:

```js
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "nishCap", {
    writable: true,
    configurable: true,
    value() {
        console.log(typeof this); // "string"
        const o = Object(this);
        console.log(typeof o);    // "object"
        return o.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + o.substring(1);
    }
});
const capped = "foo".nishCap();
```

Note that this even applies to array methods, because you can call them on non-arrays, like `Array.prototype.find.call("foo", ch => ch === "o")`.

> Is this an abbreviated way of calling `var o = new Object(this);`?

No, `new Object` always creates a new object (and doesn't use the argument you give it). When you [call `Object` as a function](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object-value), it coerces its argument to object. So a primitive string becomes a `String` object, a primitive number becomes a `Number` object, etc.

> What's the purpose of doing so instead of doing `var o = this`?

That polyfill is fairly closely following [the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.find), which starts out with:

> 1. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).

In most cases it wouldn't be important, but I wouldn't be surprised if there were some edge case where leaving it out would cause observable behavior at variance with the spec.

Comment: I have to get familiarized with the language used on the spec documents. I knew i was missing something from those comments, thanks.

Comment: @jcamejo - It takes some getting used to! One thing in particular is the use of `!` before a spec operation (described [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-returnifabrupt-shorthands)). It *doesn't* mean negation. Sometimes very tricky to read past it... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Because `Array.prototype.find` can be called with a `this` value which is *not* an object. See the [specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.find):

> When the find method is called, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).

So, in order to be perfectly compliant with the specification, the polyfill needs `Object(this)`. Otherwise, the implementations will not be the same, as you can see by the following two snippets:

```js
'use strict';
const str = 'abc';
Array.prototype.find.call(
  str,
  (char, i, theThis) => {
    // theThis should be an object, even if called on a non-object:
    console.log(theThis);
  }
);
```

```js
'use strict';
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'find', {
  value: function(predicate) {
    if (this == null) {
      throw TypeError('"this" is null or not defined');
    }

    // Without object wrapping:
    var o = this; // <-------------------------------

    var len = o.length >>> 0;

    if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
      throw TypeError('predicate must be a function');
    }

    var thisArg = arguments[1];

    var k = 0;

    while (k < len) {
      var kValue = o[k];
      if (predicate.call(thisArg, kValue, k, o)) {
        return kValue;
      }
      k++;
    }

    return undefined;
  },
  configurable: true,
  writable: true
});


const str = 'abc';
Array.prototype.find.call(
  str,
  (char, i, theThis) => {
    // The polyfill above had no object wrapping, so this result is not the same:
    console.log(theThis);
  }
);
```